# LocalStorage fire twice to store Object

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I am try to store an object into LocalStorage, but when I trigger`setItem`, its store two objects (duplicate). Below are my codes;

html

```
<form class="clearBoth"  ng-submit="addProject(projectInfo)">
      <div class="list" ng-model="projectInfo">
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
              <span class="input-label">Project Name</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="projectInfo.name" placeholder="PSN" required>
          </label>


          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
              <span class="input-label">Host</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="projectInfo.host"  placeholder="http://psn.com.my" required>
          </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Instance</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="projectInfo.instance" placeholder="PSN" required>
        </label>

      </div>


      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="addProject(projectInfo)">Block Button</button>
      <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="removeProject()">Block Button</button>
  </form>
```

controller

```
.controller("ProjectAddCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.addProject = function (projectInfo) {

        var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

        $scope.projects = [{
        name: "",
        host: "",
        instance: ""
        }];

    oldItems.push(projectInfo);
    localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));

};

    $scope.removeProject = function () { localStorage.clear(); };

    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')));


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `ng-click` on the `<button>` and `ng-submit` on the `<form>` are being triggered and hence, you are seeing the same data being added twice. You can fix it by adding `type="button"` attribute on the first button.

Check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) - the default value for the `type` attribute is `submit` and hence, both the `click` and `submit` events are being fired.

Comment: Better would be remove `ng-click="addProject(projectInfo)"` from button and let submit work properly. Making it ytpe button doesn't allow for keyboard submit

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Thank you by the way!